# Jquery Popup scrolltop

Tags: jquery, css, module, popup, scrolltop

I'm creating a basic popup with simple Jquery but instead of the popup scrolling top to the window height. Is it possible to have the popup scroll to the user view position? Thanks.

```
$(document).scroll(function(){
    if (!$("#mc_embed_signup").data('userClosed')) {
        $(".popup-close").click(function(e){
            closeSPopup(e);
        });

        var a = $(this).scrollTop();
        if (a > 350) {
          $("#mc_embed_signup").show().animate({top: (window.innerHeight / 2 - 0) + "px"}, 1800);
        }
    }
});

function closeSPopup(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#mc_embed_signup").data('userClosed',true);
    $("#mc_embed_signup").hide();
};
```

Comment: sorry let me add the code snippet in my question.

Comment: Have you considered making the position of the popup fixed?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion but it is position fixed but somehow its keep scrolling all the way to the top.

Comment: I have a couple concerns for this logic.  The first being that you are creating a click event inside a scroll handler.  This means that if the logic falls into the true part of the if, then that event will be bound multiple times.  You should avoid that as it is both performing the same work multiple times unnecessarily and can lead to issues you have to track down.  My second concern is that you are performing the animate inside the scroll event, which will happen **a lot**.  My assumption is this is why you are seeing the undesired scrolling effect some times....cont.

Comment: cont... You should consider either throttling or debouncing the logic so that only one animate is running at a given time.  An example of this can be found in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47212809/jquery-scroll-event-fire-once-per-scroll

Comment: the click event is for the popup to close, I can work out my logic again. I want the popup to scroll to the user viewpoint and the popup will start to scroll when user is scrolling down on the web page.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the effect you desire using css transition

```
<style>
    #mc_embed_signup {
        position: fixed;
        top: -500px; //position offscreen; must be at least size of the 
                       popup
        -webkit-transition: all 1.8s ease;
        -moz-transition: all 1.8s ease;
        -o-transition: all 1.8s ease;
        transition: all 1.8s ease;
    }
</style>

$(document).ready(function() {
   window.onscroll = function () { scrollFunction(); };

   scrollFunction() {
       var scrollPosition = document.documentElement.scrollTop;

       if (scrollPosition > 350) {
           $("#mc_embed_signup").show().css("top", (window.innerHeight / 
           2 - 0).toString());
       }           
   }
});
```

Comment: Hey A Franklin, thank you so much. I will try out the code and keep you posted. I appreciate your help.